# etymology of smoothness

Tags: terminology, integers, unique-factorization-domains

Let $B$ be a positive integer. A positive integer $n$ is said to be $B$*-smooth* if all the prime factors dividing $n$ are less than $B$. I was wondering about the etymology of this term. Why is such number called "smooth"?

Comment: [This guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Adleman) introduced [that name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number).

Answer (score 0):

The obvious metaphor is *smooth $=$ fine-grained*.